# What is the highest test innings without a century being scored?

Tags: cricket

In the second test between South Africa and Bangladesh  currently underway the South Africans scored 452 in there 1st innings without a batsman scoring a century. That made me wonder what the highest test innings without a century being scored was and if this innings between the Proteas and the tigers is anywhere close to the highest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highest inning total not to contain a century is India vs New Zealand in 1976/77.

> The highest inning total not to contain a century is India’s 524/9
> against New Zealand at Kanpur in 1976/77. The highest score in the
> inning was not even 75. There were six individual half-centuries and
> the highest score was 70 by Mohinder Amarnath.

Source: [Highest Test totals without a century and half-century](https://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/highest-test-totals-without-a-century-and-half-century)

> In November 1976 the team established another record by scoring 524
> for 9 declared against New Zealand at Kanpur without an individual
> scoring a century.

Source: [crickhistoryworld/history/india](https://sites.google.com/site/crickhistoryworld/history/india)

Scorecard for this game:

1. [2nd Test, Kanpur, November 18 - 23, 1976,
   New Zealand tour of India](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/new-zealand-tour-of-india-1976-77-62128/india-vs-new-zealand-2nd-test-63172/full-scorecard)
2. [Test Match - India v New Zealand - Kanpur](http://www.howstat.com/cricket/statistics/Matches/MatchScorecard.asp?MatchCode=0786)

See also: [Eight tons in a Test, and high totals without a hundred](https://www.espncricinfo.com/story/eight-tons-in-a-test-and-high-totals-without-a-hundred-295485)

Answer (score 2):

As of today it's Sri Lanka's 531 all out vs Bangladesh!

https://wisden.com/series-stories/bangladesh-v-sri-lanka/after-lowest-total-200-run-stand-sri-lanka-highest-test-total-without-hundred

https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/bangladesh-vs-sri-lanka-2023-24-1419819/bangladesh-vs-sri-lanka-2nd-test-1419831/live-cricket-score

Comment: Could we get you to give a short synopsis of the links? Link-only answers are generally frowned upon.